# SQL require table name in values section

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, sql-insert, string-literals

I am trying to store the data in table by using insert query (I am using **PostreSQL**), but there is it.

```
ERROR:  column "Fleet" does not exist
LINE 1: insert into appuser values("Fleet")
```

Postresql require column name in values section, but what is that? Why? (There is only test, my '**appuser**' table has 2 columns, one of it is primary key auto-generated, so do not get confuse)

Comment: Please provide the SQL query you are using.

Comment: Use single quotes for value 'Fleet'

Comment: what is your table-definition?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your table has two columns and you are providing a value for only one, so you need to tell the database which one it is. Also, literal strings must be surrounded with single quotes (double quotes stand for column identifiers).

Assuming that the target column is `mycol`, that would be:

```
insert into appuser (mycol) values('Fleet')
```

Comment: I have tried, but the result is completely the same!